# Team fortress blue screen and random color pixels (13.4)

Tags: intel-graphics, steam

I'm trying to run team frotress 2 on my laptop.
I have intel integrated card(About dialog says: Intel® Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2) and i3 processor.
I have 13.04 and latests drivers. Here's a screen shot of when I run it(windowed or regular its the same.)

[image]

I have tried to play tf2 on elementaryOS(based on 12.04) and it was the same problem.

Can i run it?

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU P6200 @ 2.13GHz × 2
Intel® Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2 on Ubuntu 13.04

Go to Ubuntu Software Center >edit >software sources... >other software >add...

add this line > deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu raring main

then go to the dash, software updater, install and reboot.

Enjoy your hats ;).

Comment: Using PPAs is a risk and as such you should check the specified PPA carefully before using them.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I should add that by doing this, you install the Mesa graphic driver.

Comment: What drivers are these? I have intell's drivers... the newest, are these somehow better?